# Process gzip files with Hadoop-streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, compression, hadoop-streaming

I saw many posts about output the hadoop MapReduce result to gzip format or any other compressed format.  However, I don't see much about how hadoop-streaming read in (input) the compressed format.  I saw some older post about using `-jobconf stream.recordreader.compression=gzip` http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/200907.mbox/%3C73e5a5310907141349k3329c5cua4bb58fcf103522@mail.gmail.com%3E to do the input part.  Currently, I am using Cloudera CDH 5 on Ubuntu LTS 12.04.  Writing mapper and reducer with python.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Streaming should handle gzip'd files automatically.

Answer (score 5):

No additional command line args are needed, Gzip input is natively supported by Hadoop streaming jobs.  Gzip files will automatically be detected and decompressed.  Just pass gzip files using the -input option.  Here is a very simple example:

`$ hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -input /user/johndoe/test_input.gz -output /user/johndoe/output -mapper /bin/cat -reducer /usr/bin/wc`

In terms of input, using a Python mapper and reducer will not change anything.

One caveat I've notice but have yet to resolve: using gzip input with the `-inputreader "StreamXmlRecordReader,begin=page,end=/page"` option produces no output.